# jQuery: IF conditions for multiple radio button fields?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements, radio-button

https://jsfiddle.net/fbzf10x6/6/

```
  <form action="">
<input type="radio" name="colour" value="black"> black
<br>
<input type="radio" name="colour" value="white"> white
<br>

<br>

<input type="radio" name="form" value="round"> round
<br>
<input type="radio" name="form" value="triangle"> triangle
<br>
```

There are two form-fields "colour" and "forms" with radio buttons that decide which image to show. Choosing the colour works as seen in the fiddle.

If the user now checks triangle in the second field (name="forms") I want a white triangle to show. If he checks black in "colour" and "round" in forms it should change the img src to black_round.jpg and so on.

This is a simplified version. I will have many fields and many more options in the end.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should have to take of "The image names must be like black_round.jpg, black_triangle.jpg, white_round.jpg, white_triangle.jpg" to make the following snippet work in your case.

Please check below snippet for more understanding. You should have to check the image src by inspect element because no image will load currently as such we have not those images currently. But you can rename image names on your server and check with this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var imgname = [];
  $("input[name=colour]").click(function() {
    imgname['colour'] = $(this).val();
      if(Object.keys(imgname).length == 2){
        $("#image").attr('src',imgname['colour'] +'_'+ imgname['form']+'.jpg');
      }
  });
  
  $("input[name=form]").click(function() {
    imgname['form'] = $(this).val();
      if(Object.keys(imgname).length == 2){
        $("#image").attr('src',imgname['colour'] +'_'+ imgname['form']+'.jpg');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="black"> black
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="colour" value="white"> white
    <br>

    <br>

    <input type="radio" name="form" value="round"> round
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="form" value="triangle"> triangle
    <br>

  </form>

  <div><img id="image" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MuBXtqpPw7s/T31fChtWOOI/AAAAAAAAAWI/QRpSQv__DcM/s320/black%2B9.png"></div>
```